# Where should I put a custom theme in Aquamacs?

Tags: themes, aquamacs

I found a vivid chalk color scheme [here](https://github.com/chongli/emacs/blob/master/colors/vivid-chalk.el) that I want to use with Aquamacs.  After poking around, I discovered that Aquamacs stores its custom color schemes here:

```
/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/
color-theme-library.el
```

That file contains the color schemes that I see when I do:

```
M-x custom-schemes
```

I don't really feel like messing around with that file.  The Aquamacs `Preferences.el` file is in the directory:

```
 ~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs$
```

Can I store third party custom themes in that directory somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The [file you reference](https://github.com/chongli/emacs/blob/master/colors/vivid-chalk.el) is an old-style "color-theme". These can be dropped anywhere in your `load-path`. You can also add any directory to your load path. Personally I like to keep my color-themes in `~/.emacs.d/lisp`. A minimal init-file that updates your load path and loads your theme would look like:

```
;; prepend personal lisp directory to the load-path                           
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp"))
;; load a fancy new theme
(require 'color-theme)
(require 'vivid-chalk)
(color-theme-vivid-chalk)
```